# Magento2 Category field Custom Layout Update - add handle and declaration of handle file

Tags: magento2, category, layout, layout-update

In Magento 2, has anyone tried to add an update handle in "Custom Layout Update" on the category admin page? I've set the following on a category:

```
<update handle="my_handle_lorem_ipsum_lorem" />
```

And I created the following file in my current theme:

```
[theme dir]/Magento_Catalog/layout/my_handle_lorem_ipsum_lorem.xml
```

However, the update handle doesn't appear to be applied.

I know the XML directives in `my_handle_lorem_ipsum_lorem.xml` are correct because they work correctly when placed in `[theme dir]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_id_123.xml`.

By debugging I've found that the "Custom Layout Update" attribute is handled here:

```
// \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View::execute() [excerpt]

$layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates();
if ($layoutUpdates && is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
    foreach ($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
        $page->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
    }
}
```

Tracing the source of `$layoutUpdates`, I found that it ultimately gets set in `_extractSettings()` of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Design`:

```
// \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design::_extractSettings() [excerpt]

$settings->setCustomDesign(
    $object->getCustomDesign()
)->setPageLayout(
    $object->getPageLayout()
)->setLayoutUpdates(
    (array)$object->getCustomLayoutUpdate()
);
```

That pulls the entire string `<update handle="my_handle_lorem_ipsum_lorem" />` from the category attribute. Does that mean it's trying to use the entire string as the handle name?

All I see is the call to `addUpdate()`. There doesn't seem to be a call to any function of the `Merge` class that would incorporate it into the overall layout XML.

In general, how should we add a handle in the category field "Custom Layout Update," and where and how should the file should be declared?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. I have verified that the category layout update xml is actually loaded and used (I can f.e. remove blocks), but the handle update seems ignored. were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I haven't found a fix. Try a Magento 2.1 installation, maybe it's fixed there.

Comment: It is not, unfortunately. As a workaround, I use a plugin to manually add the layout handle after checking the currently loaded category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying to solve a similar issue, so I'm reading through the code pretty extensively to get to the root of this. I'll start at the end and work backward:

The call to `addUpdate()` you reference actually does end up calling `addUpdate()` on the `\Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge` class. Hold onto your seat: it's a bumpy road. The `$page` variable is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Result`, and it inherits the definition of `addUpdate()` from its parent class `Layout` (in the same namespace). That class in turn calls `addUpdate()` on a `ProcessorInterface`, whose default implementation is none other than: `Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge`.

So then to your question about it seeming to pass the entire XML string: you are correct, and the behavior is correct. The `Merge` class should theoretically be taking care of parsing the `<update>` inside `_fetchRecursiveUpdates()` and then loading the layout XML from the referenced handle.

The catch is that `_fetchRecursiveUpdates()` is never called on XML chunks that are added via `addUpdate()`. They are assumed to be ready-to-go (non-recursive) layout instructions. Layout XML from external `addUpdate()` calls are included directly via a call to `$this->asString()` at the very end of `Merge::load()`. They never pass through the inner `_merge()` function which is what indirectly calls `_fetchRecursiveUpdates()`.

A simplistic solution would be to create a new class that extends the built-in `Merge` class and set it as the preferred implementation of `ProcessorInterface`. You would then change the `addUpdate()` method to perform the same logic as `_fetchRecursiveUpdates()` before saving its argument to the internal array, something like the following:

```
public function addUpdate($update)
{
    $updateXml = $this->_loadXmlString($update);
    if (strtolower($updateXml->getName()) == 'update' && isset($updateXml['handle'])) {
        $this->_merge((string)$updateXml['handle']);
    } else {
        $this->updates[] = $update;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I just discovered that this has been acknowledged as a bug by Magento: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5901